# How to get Jenkins to push build status to Github from behind a firewall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server that is behind a firewall (Boss's Orders), can't be accessed outside of the office unless on the vpn. I'm trying to set up continous integration for our rails team. I have the job to run our tests going whenever there is a commit/merge in the publicly hosted repo on github.com. My question is, how do I go about setting up my server to be able to push the status of the related tests to the pull request located on github to ensure it is unable to be merged unless all the tests passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was a post status to Github in my post build options. 
That successfully gave me the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your firewall prevents outgoing connections, your Jenkins instance should be able to update the status on github without problems.

Comment: Is there a specific plugin I should be using ? Or can you point me in the direction of a useful blog post.